# Bash redirecting output to a file from awk

Tags: bash, awk, tee

I am trying to output to a file only the IPs of the string that start with `{ G :` currently the way I am doing it below will output the IPs to the terminal but when I add the `>> $IP_LOG` at the end of it, it creates a log but it is empty. Without the `>> $IP_LOG` i can see the output correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash
..
..
ssh root@server 'tail -f /var/log/server.log' | tee $LOG | grep --line-buffered "{ G :" | awk -F'[][]' -v n=2 '{ print$(2*n) }' >> $IP_LOG
```

Comment: The output from `awk` is buffered.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33650/why-does-awk-do-full-buffering-when-reading-from-a-pipe

Comment: so a possible fix is add `; system("")` to the awk part.